# Split string with commas to new line

Tags: javascript, split

I have a string like

```
This is great day, tomorrow is a better day, the day after is a better day, the day after the day after that is the greatest day
```

I wanted to basically split this one long string at the commas and insert a new line so it becomes

```
This is great day
tomorrow is a better day
the day after is a better day
the day after the day after that is the greatest day
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Can we achieve the same functionality in underscore.js?

Comment: Please give me suggestion how to break line after every 5 comma in string.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

With the built in [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods

```
var formattedString = yourString.split(",").join("\n")
```

If you'd like the newlines to be HTML line breaks that would be

```
var formattedString = yourString.split(",").join("<br />")
```

This makes the most sense to me since you're splitting it into lines and then joining them with the newline character.

Although I think speed is less important than readability in most cases, I was curious about it in this case  so I've written a quick a [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/split-vs-replace-so).

It seems that (in chrome) using `str.split(",").join("\n")` is faster than `str.replace(/,/g, '\n');` .

Comment: awesome thanks - so doing this in html is just something like `yourString.split(",").join("<br/>")`

Comment: `string.replace(',', '\n')` only replaces the first comma with a newline.

Comment: @Blender That is correct! I guess I never used replace without a regexp. Was curios when I saw it as an answer, thanks, I'll update the perf

Answer (score 5):

You could also replace them:

```
string.replace(/,/g, '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<p id="errorMessage">Click | the |button |to |display| the| array| values| 
after| the| split.</p>

$(document).ready(function () {
var str = $("#errorMessage").text();
document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML=str.split("|").join(" 
</br>"); }
```

Comment: Don't just blurt out code! Adding some text to describe how this best answers the question will improve the long-term value of the answer and help to prevent it from being deleted during review. Also, it may not be obvious to all readers how this solves the problem being that the split character provided by the OP was `,` rather than `|`.

Answer (score 0):

```
> a = 'This is great day, tomorrow is a better day, the day after is a better day, the day after the day after that is the greatest day'
> b = a.split(', ').join('\n')

"This is great day
tomorrow is a better day
the day after is a better day
the day after the day after that is the greatest day"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split()` to create an array of all the parts of the string...

```
var str = 'This is great day, tomorrow is a better day, the day after is a better day, the day after the day after that is the greatest day';

str.split(',');
  -> ["This is great day", " tomorrow is a better day", " the day after is a better day", " the day after the day after that is the greatest day"]
```

Now, you can do whatever you want with the different parts. Since you want to join with a new line, you can use `.join()` to put it back together...

```
str.split(',').join('\n');
  -> "This is great day
      tomorrow is a better day
      the day after is a better day
      the day after the day after that is the greatest day"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TermsAndConditions = "Right to make changes to the agreement.,Copyright and intellectual property.,Governing law.,Warrantaay disclaimer.,Limitation of liability."
```

```
const TAndCList = this.invoiceTermsAndConditions.split(",").join("\n \n• ");
```

***Output :***

```
• Right to make changes to the agreement.
• Copyright and intellectual property.
• Governing law.
• Warrantaay disclaimer.
• Limitation of liability.
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest split the array on commas and then use the for loop. below code snippet is for vue.js

```
             <div 
             v-for="(arrayElement) in Array"
             :key="`Array-${arrayElement.id}`"
             class="column">
                {{ arrayElement.name }}
             </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Without testing on my browser try:

```
var MyStr="This is great day, tomorrow is a better day, the day after is a better day, the day after the day after that is the greatest day";
Var splitedStr = MyStr.split(",");

var returnStr = '';
for (var i = 0; i < splitedStr.length; i++)
{
    returnStr += splitedStr[i] + '<br />';
}

document.write(returnStr);
```

Comment: `document.write` is not safe anymore