# angular split().join() not working for new line

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

```
    let samplestring ="a:b;c:d;e:f"
    this.detail = samplestring.split(";").join("\n");
```

> ```
> <div fxLayout="row">
>     <span class="default_label_font">{{detail}}</span>
>   </div>
> ```

but not adding new line and giving response like 
response sample i'm getting
[image]

I've tried using "
" too but instead of adding break it concatenate it

I refer [Split string with commas to new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375886/split-string-with-commas-to-new-line)

Comment: How are you displaying this string? How do you set it string as text? What element you use to set?

Comment: in a popup i've edit in question

Comment: You can also use a regex like `"a:b;c:d;e:f".replace(/;/g, '\n')` but new lines will only appear in a console, not in an HTML page where you have to use `<br>` instead of `\n`

Comment: let me try stephane ..    but why this is not working it should right?

Comment: @Himanshi see my answer for more details, but no. `\n` is not rendered by HTML at all, unless rendered by `<pre>` element.

Comment: As I said `\n` won't work in HTML page unless its supported either by the tag (like `<pre>` or the CSS)

Comment: @StephaneJanicaud no impact same as before

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render a string in HTML and preserve spaces and linebreaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492249/render-a-string-in-html-and-preserve-spaces-and-linebreaks)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it, I think much simpler, is to use `[innerHtml]` ([docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-vs-interpolation)) instead of interpolation and break lines with `<br>`.

Like this:

```html
<div fxLayout="row">
  <span class="default_label_font" [innerHtml]="detail"></span>
</div>
```

```js
let samplestring = "a:b;c:d;e:f";
this.detail = samplestring.split(";").join("<br>");
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-split-innerhtml-breakline) for you to test and play.

Comment: still gives me this            a:b<br>c:d<br>e:f

Comment: Did you update your HTML to use `[innerHtml]="detail"` instead of `{{ detail }}` like I showed you in my answer?

Comment: yes now i did previously used with {{}}  it worked big thanks

Comment: short solution  great reputation is low so cant vote but this worked

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print the text on separate lines you will have to add `<br>` inbetween. `\n` is not rendered by HTML, unless you use `<pre>`.

extract from component.ts

```
this.lines = samplestring.split(";");
```

extract from component.html

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let line of lines; i = index">
  <br *ngIf="i != 0">{{line}}
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is the element you are using to set. `Span` is a inline component. So line breaks will not work. You will have to use a block level element like `Div`

```js
let samplestring = "a:b;c:d;e:f"
const detail = samplestring.split(";").join("\n");

document.querySelector('.default_label_font').innerText = detail;
```

```html
<div fxLayout="row">
  <div class="default_label_font"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, its not jQuery. Second, this is to depict the use of correct element. I can help you solve the issue not your code

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<h1 id="ovde">
      ...
    </h1>
```

ts

```
let customItems = "1,2,3";
  customItems = customItems.split(',');

  for ( let i = 0; i < customItems.length; i++ )
    customItems[i] = "- " + customItems[i] + "\n";

  customItems = customItems.join('');

  document.getElementById("ovde").innerHTML = customItems;
```

Comment: angular way please

Comment: const elements = ['Fire', 'Air', 'Water'];

console.log(elements.join());
// expected output: "Fire,Air,Water"

console.log(elements.join(''));
// expected output: "FireAirWater"

console.log(elements.join('-'));